# Wifi connected but can't access any Website

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport, internet

When trying to connect to Wi-Fi it connects without a problem and it is showing that Wi-Fi has full signal strength. However when trying to access any website it shows that it is trying to load it and just hangs at that point. What is causing this?
What can be done to resolve this? The router in question is a Aruba Networks Router with WPA2 enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and click the Wi-Fi symbol in the menu bar; in the extended menu does it list the Internet as reachable? 
If not, it can be a external problem or perhaps there is a secondary login required on a splash website or something.